# Custom Authentication Provider get calls with every request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am creating a custom authentication provider that authenticates user using a third party system. Username and password are being sent to server in json format. To implement that I have created a custom filter - UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter which is called at position FORM_LOGIN_FILTER. After this I created a custom authentication provider to authenticate user using a third party system. But, this authentication filter is being called with every request, which causes third party system to be called with every request. What I am doing wrong?

CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    //Get username password from request
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = 
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken( username, password);
    setDetails(request, token);
    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
}
```

Custom Authentication Provider:

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
      String username = authentication.getName();
      String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
      boolean flag = //use the credentials to try to authenticate against the third party system
    if(flag) {
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
    }
    else
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Credentials");
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return true;
}
```

security-context.xml

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/welcome"
      create-session="always" disable-url-rewriting="true" entry-point-ref="customEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access='permitAll'/>
    <custom-filter ref="loginFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-url="/logout"  invalidate-session="true" />
</http>

<bean id="loginFilter" class="org.temp.secure.CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="requiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher" ref="loginRequestUrlHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="username" />
    <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="password" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<bean id="loginRequestUrlHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RegexRequestMatcher">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="/login" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="POST" />
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="customEntryPoint" class="org.temp.secure.CustomEntryPoint" />

<bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="org.temp.secure.MyAuthenticationProvider"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, got it, problem was that I was not setting any roles, so it was showing authentication as false. After setting roles in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, it does not call custom authentication provider any more..

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
    boolean flag = //use the credentials to try to authenticate against the third party system
    if(flag) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ONE"));
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_TWO"));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities);
   }
   else
       throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Credentials"); 
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you please tell where did you configured CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter. Also was there any need of writing CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter? only making use of "Custom Authentication Provider" would have worked.

Comment: Saved my day. I was implementing custom authentication with custom `Authentication` implementation and set `authenticated` to `false` by default, without changing it anywhere later.  My `AuthenticationProvider` was triggered each call. Setting it to `true` after successful authentication fixed my issue.

Comment: Agreeing with @OlegKuts, I need to set `AuthenticationToken.setAuthenticated(true)` to fix the same issue.